# Python Linked List implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, linked-list

I am looking for some comments on an implementation of a singly-linked list in Python. What could I do to make it more reliable and readable?

```
class LinkedList(object):
    class Node(object):
        """
        Inner class of LinkedList. Contains a blueprint for a node of the LinkedList
        """
        def __init__(self, v, n=None):
            """
            Initializes a List node with payload v and link n
            """
            self.value=v
            self.next=n

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes a LinkedList and sets list head to None
        """
        self.head=None

    def insert(self, v):
        """
        Adds an item with payload v to beginning of the list
        in O(1) time 
        """
        Node = self.Node(v, self.head)
        self.head = Node

    def size(self):
        """
        Returns the current size of the list. O(n), linear time
        """
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.next
        return count

    def search(self, v):
        """
        Searches the list for a node with payload v. Returns the node object or None if not found. Time complexity is O(n) in worst case.
        """
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current and not found:
            if current.value == v:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.next
        if not current:
            return None
        return current

    def delete(self, v):
        """
        Searches the list for a node with payload v. Returns the node object or None if not found. Time complexity is O(n) in worst case.
        """
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while current and not found:
            if current.value == v:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.next
        # nothing found, return None
        if not current:
            return None
        # the case where first item is being deleted
        if not previous:
            self.head = current.next
        # item from inside of the list is being deleted    
        else:
            previous.next = current.next

        return current

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Prints the current list in the form of a Python list            
        """
        current = self.head
        toPrint = []
        while current != None:
            toPrint.append(current.value)
            current = current.next
        return str(toPrint)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"more reliable"*?

Comment: Fewer possible bugs.

Comment: I rolled back your edits, because once you have answers changing the question code is not possible, in order to avoid invalidating existing answers. Have a look at [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). You can always ask a follow-up question with the updated code.

Comment: Sure. No problem.

Answer (score 6):

If readability is a concern, why use single-character variable names? Replace them with something a bit more meaningful: `v` -> `value`, `n` -> `next_`, etc.

---

If you followed Python's [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) your class could be used more easily and conventionally. For example, implementing `size` as a method seems a bit odd - if you called it [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), then it would behave correctly with `len` and in a boolean context. Looking at the documentation for other, similar data structures can help with picking sensible names (I would expect an `insert` to take an index, for example, like [the other sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)); in your case, maybe start with the [`deque`'s interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

If you follow the conventional implementation, any of the following should work in a predictable way:

- `if thing in linked_list:`
- `for thing in linked_list:`
- `list(linked_list)` (which would really simplify your `__str__` implementation)
- `if linked_list:`

You could also leverage Python's abstract base classes; if you inherit from [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) and implement the required methods, for example, you get some additional behaviour for free.

---

In general you're following the style guide, but `Node` as a temporary variable name sticks out. It shadows the class you just instantiated and naming a variable in `CamelCase` is not the convention, it should be `snake_case`. In fact, it's entirely pointless; why not just `self.node = Node(v, self.head)`?

Comment: Do you know if I need to create a separate class to implement an iterator? That is, I am trying to implement `for thing in linked_list:` functionality.

Comment: Is this a valid example? http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/understanding-python-iterables-and.html

Answer (score 4):

To make @jonrsharpe's suggestion more specific, this is one way to implement `__iter__`, without having to add another iterator class. It also gives you the `__str__` method for free.

```
def __iter__(self):
    """
    Iterate over the linked list.
    """
    current = self.head
    while current is not None:
        yield current.value
        current = current.next

def __str__(self):
    """
    Prints the current list in the form of a Python list
    """
    return str(list(self))
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```
>>> l = LinkedList()
>>> l.insert(1)
>>> l.insert(2)
>>> for x in l:
...     print x
... 
2
1
>>> list(l)
[2, 1]
>>> print(l)
[2, 1]
```

Note that I used `is not None` instead of `!= None`, read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not), if you want to know why.

Comment: Would such `__str__` method print a string version of memory addresses to the Nodes? If so, how is this useful to someone using such method?

Comment: Also, could you take a look at my implementation of `iter()` and `next()` that I added as an edit to the original post?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Regarding question 1, I don't understand your question. For `l = LinkedList; l.insert(1); l.insert(2)` `list(l) == [2, 1]` and `print(l)` will just print `[2, 1]`. This works because the `__iter__` method is yielding the values, not the `Node` objects.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Regarding question 2, have a look at the comment on the question. Once you receive answers you must not change your code in your question anymore. You can, however, ask a new question with the updated code (and link to the new one here and to this question in the new question).

Comment: What i was wondering about is which double underscore method one needs to implement to have it react to 'list()' called with the class as the parameter?

Comment: And i understand about the question policy. Should i add a link to the original question or in the comments?

Comment: @MadPhysicist. `__iter__` is enough for that, see the example in my updated answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Just put it somewhere in the question body, like, this is a continued discussion from *link*, since I incorporated some advice gotten there. Or something similar